# AWCC Install Alienware 13

Tags: laptop, installation

A friend of mine had an Alienware 13 bought about a year ago, and when his AWCC(Alienware Command Center, a software for controlling the lighting and power settings) was malfunctioning. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling after some preliminary steps didn't work, but I couldn't find a download link. AWCC 3.5 isn't made for the 13", only 14,17,18 I believe. Is there a version for the 13"?

Comment: You are going to have to tell us what `AWCC` is exactly if you want help.

Comment: @Ramhound OK, done

Comment: There has to be a version, or else he wouldn't have got one. However, I believe that he should have had a restore disk (by alienware) for reinstalling software.

Comment: @RookieTEC9 There isn't a disk in the box it came in